# Grothendieck group of a quaternion algebra

Tags: quaternions

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a maximal order in a quaternion algebra over a number field.  Then there is a notion of similarity of (left) $\mathcal{O}$-modules, and similarity classes.  The set $S$ of such classes is like a class group of a number field, except it is just a pointed set.  It has an adelic description which you can find in Proposition 13 [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/SC9-Orders.pdf).  On the other hand, we can form the Grothendieck group of the category of projective left modules over $\mathcal{O}$.  This maps to $\mathbb{Z}$ by the "rank" map.  The kernel is a group $G$.  My questions are:

1. Does $G$ have the same size as $S$?
2. Is $S$ a torsor for $G$ in a natural way?
3. Is there a simple description of $G$ (adelic or otherwise) in terms of $\mathcal{O}$ that doesn't reference the Grothendieck group construction?